# rentrez error HTTP failure: 400 when downloading >1/3 of records

Tags: r, rentrez

I have a weird situation. I am mining PubMed data using `rentrez`. When I run `entrez_search()` and then `entrez_summary()` and then `entrez_fetch()` I get the message this error (full code at the bottom of post):

```
Error: HTTP failure: 400
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE eEfetchResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD efetch 20131226//EN" "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20131226/efetch.dtd">
<eFetchResult>
    <ERROR>Cannot retrieve history data. query_key: 1, WebEnv: NCID_1_51629226_130.14.18.34_9001_1531773486_1795859931_0MetA0_S_MegaStore, retstart: 0, retmax: 552</ERROR>
    <ERROR>Can't fetch uids from history because of: NCBI C++ Exception:
    Error: UNK_MODULE(CException::eInvalid) "UNK_FILE", line 18446744073709551615: UNK_FUNC --- 
</ERROR>
</eFetchResult>
```

After searching around, I thought I had found the solution in [this discussion](https://github.com/ropensci/rentrez/issues/74) of query size. When I decreased `retmax_set` from 500 to 10, the code worked. I then iteratively determined the maximum `retmax_set` value that would not throw an error and discovered what seems to me to be very weird behavior.

The search `term_set = "transcription AND enhancer AND promoter AND 2017:2018[PDAT]"` yeilds 552 records. When running my code with different values of `retmax`:

- setting `retmax_set` <= 183 works
- setting `retmax_set` >= 184 gives the error described above

A modified search `term_set = "transcription AND enhancer AND promoter AND 2018[PDAT]"` yeilds 186 records. When running this search with different values of `retmax`:

- setting `retmax_set` <= 61 works
- setting `retmax_set` >= 62 gives the error described above

The search `term_set = "transcription AND enhancer AND promoter AND 2017[PDAT]"` yeilds 395 records (for some reason PubMed labels 29 records as being published in 2017 and 2018). When running my code on this search term with different values of `retmax`:

- setting `retmax_set` <= 131 works
- setting `retmax_set` >= 132 gives the error described above

Interestingly, all three searches start to fail when the `retmax` value is greater than one third of the total number of records (552 / 3 = 184, 186 / 3 = 62, 395 / 3 = 131.67). I'm going to modify my code to calculate `retmax_set` based on the number of results returned by `entrez_search`, but I have no idea why `rentrez` or NCBI is doing this. Any ideas?

```
> ##  set search term 
> term_set = "transcription AND enhancer AND promoter AND 2017:2018[PDAT]"
> ##  load package
> library(rentrez)
> ##  set maximum records batch
> retmax_set = 182
> ##  search pubmed using web history
> search <- entrez_search(
+   db = "pubmed", 
+   term = term_set, 
+   use_history = T
+ )
> ##  get summaries of search hits 
> summary <- list(); for (seq_start in seq(0, search$count - 1, retmax_set)) {
+     summary1 <- entrez_summary(
+         db = "pubmed", 
+         web_history = search$web_history, 
+         retmax = retmax_set, 
+         retstart = seq_start
+     )
+     summary <- c(summary, summary1)
+ }
> ##  download full XML refs for hits
> XML_refs <- entrez_fetch(
+     db = "pubmed", 
+     web_history = search$web_history, 
+     rettype = "xml", 
+     parsed = TRUE
+ )
> 
> 
> ##  set search term 
> term_set = "transcription AND enhancer AND promoter AND 2017:2018[PDAT]"
> ##  load package
> library(rentrez)
> ##  set maximum records batch
> retmax_set = 183
> ##  search pubmed using web history
> search <- entrez_search(
+   db = "pubmed", 
+   term = term_set, 
+   use_history = T
+ )
> ##  get summaries of search hits 
> summary <- list(); for (seq_start in seq(0, search$count - 1, retmax_set)) {
+     summary1 <- entrez_summary(
+         db = "pubmed", 
+         web_history = search$web_history, 
+         retmax = retmax_set, 
+         retstart = seq_start
+     )
+     summary <- c(summary, summary1)
+ }
> ##  download full XML refs for hits
> XML_refs <- entrez_fetch(
+     db = "pubmed", 
+     web_history = search$web_history, 
+     rettype = "xml", 
+     parsed = TRUE
+ )
> 
> 
> ##  set search term 
> term_set = "transcription AND enhancer AND promoter AND 2017:2018[PDAT]"
> ##  load package
> library(rentrez)
> ##  set maximum records batch
> retmax_set = 184
> ##  search pubmed using web history
> search <- entrez_search(
+   db = "pubmed", 
+   term = term_set, 
+   use_history = T
+ )
> ##  get summaries of search hits 
> summary <- list(); for (seq_start in seq(0, search$count - 1, retmax_set)) {
+     summary1 <- entrez_summary(
+         db = "pubmed", 
+         web_history = search$web_history, 
+         retmax = retmax_set, 
+         retstart = seq_start
+     )
+     summary <- c(summary, summary1)
+ }
> ##  download full XML refs for hits
> XML_refs <- entrez_fetch(
+     db = "pubmed", 
+     web_history = search$web_history, 
+     rettype = "xml", 
+     parsed = TRUE
+ )
Error: HTTP failure: 400
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE eEfetchResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD efetch 20131226//EN" "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20131226/efetch.dtd">
<eFetchResult>
    <ERROR>Cannot retrieve history data. query_key: 1, WebEnv: NCID_1_51629226_130.14.18.34_9001_1531773486_1795859931_0MetA0_S_MegaStore, retstart: 0, retmax: 552</ERROR>
    <ERROR>Can't fetch uids from history because of: NCBI C++ Exception:
    Error: UNK_MODULE(CException::eInvalid) "UNK_FILE", line 18446744073709551615: UNK_FUNC --- 
</ERROR>
</eFetchResult>
> 
> 
> ##  set search term 
> term_set = "transcription AND enhancer AND promoter AND 2017:2018[PDAT]"
> ##  load package
> library(rentrez)
> ##  set maximum records batch
> retmax_set = 185
> ##  search pubmed using web history
> search <- entrez_search(
+   db = "pubmed", 
+   term = term_set, 
+   use_history = T
+ )
> ##  get summaries of search hits 
> summary <- list(); for (seq_start in seq(0, search$count - 1, retmax_set)) {
+     summary1 <- entrez_summary(
+         db = "pubmed", 
+         web_history = search$web_history, 
+         retmax = retmax_set, 
+         retstart = seq_start
+     )
+     summary <- c(summary, summary1)
+ }
> ##  download full XML refs for hits
> XML_refs <- entrez_fetch(
+     db = "pubmed", 
+     web_history = search$web_history, 
+     rettype = "xml", 
+     parsed = TRUE
+ )
Error: HTTP failure: 400
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE eEfetchResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD efetch 20131226//EN" "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20131226/efetch.dtd">
<eFetchResult>
    <ERROR>Cannot retrieve history data. query_key: 1, WebEnv: NCID_1_52654089_130.14.22.215_9001_1531773493_484860305_0MetA0_S_MegaStore, retstart: 0, retmax: 552</ERROR>
    <ERROR>Can't fetch uids from history because of: NCBI C++ Exception:
    Error: UNK_MODULE(CException::eInvalid) "UNK_FILE", line 18446744073709551615: UNK_FUNC --- 
</ERROR>
</eFetchResult>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out rentrez uses 0-base counting. So the 552 records correspond to `retstart` values of 0 to 551. Since my code was looking for values 1 to 552 it missed the first record (#0) and then threw an error when it looked for the non-existent record #552.